# Problems with baking Ambient Occlusion

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

I'm Back with another issue, this time the same mesh, however I'm trying to bake the ambient occlusion for the model. The UV work isn't great but it shouldn't make a difference.

My main problem is the Tv screen portion again, as it comes out extremely blocky. I checked and recalculated all my normals numerous times. Here's a picture of my current issue. I'll include the Blend file as well this time.

[image: Bugged Out TV screen Mesh]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cntp6471prz7vcw/TvHeadCreature41.blend?dl=0

Comment: The dropbox link is broken.

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry for the issues. Couldn't figure out how else to upload it to here

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ exclusively for BlenderSE. Links to other file services are not reliable because the files tend to "vanish" over time, thus making questions and possible answers eventually useless.

Comment: Apologies again! I'm a bit new to the way stack exchange and this community works! I'll edit it asap

Comment: Also be sure to use "File - External Data - Pack All into .blend" if you have questions regarding textures. This will create a neat package with all the relevant data we need to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry again! I can't seem to upload it to the file service right now, so if it's alright I'll temporarily use a dropbox link. I'll try uploading it again later today to the blend exchange